# PHP include path error

Tags: php

I keep getting an error when I try to include simpletest in my include_path:

```
<?
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . realpath(basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../'));

include 'simpletest/autorun.php';
```

returns:

```
.:/usr/lib/php:/Users/kristiannissen/Documents/php
Warning: require_once(/Users/kristiannissen/Documents/php/simpletest/arguments.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/kristiannissen/Documents/php/simpletest/reporter.php on line 13

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Users/kristiannissen/Documents/php/simpletest/arguments.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/Users/kristiannissen/Documents/php') in /Users/kristiannissen/Documents/php/simpletest/reporter.php on line 13
```

Comment: Anyone ever figure out how to solve this? SimpleTest doesn't appear to work without the arguments.php file. I downloaded and substituted in the one from the PHP4 version of SimpleTest, but it is not a compatible replacement for the missing file.

Comment: Success. SimpleTest 1.0.1 works with CakePHP 1.3.7.

Comment: I downloaded version 1.0.1 and it work OK, it contains a lot of deprecation warnings but you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally your view pages are the first executed, such as index.php and view pages should always be in the root of your html.

so within index.php you can do:

```
define("BASE_PATH",str_replace("\\","/",dirname(__FILE__)));
```

so now `BASE_PATH` would be equal to: `/Users/kristiannissen/Documents/php/simpletest`

So if you want to `php`directory in your include path you should use `dirname()` to go **UP** a directory:

```
//Get an array of your include paths
$include_parts = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR,get_include_path());

//Extend the paths
$include_parts[] = dirname(dirname(BASE_PATH)); //this is ../../

//recompile the paths and set them
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$include_parts));
```

this is the safe way to accomplish what your trying to do.

Comment: After having spent more time on this I found out that it wasn't my include path that was the problem but simpletest. It looks as if arguments.php is missing from the folder, I tried to download it again but it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alpha2-release on sourceforge that has the arguments.php-require commented out.  I guess it isn't needed anymore.